# AWS - NLB Performance Issue

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gateway, nlb

## AWS

I am using network load balancer infront of private VPC in the API gateway. Basically for APIs in the gateway the endpoint is network load balancer's DNS name.

The issue is, performance sucks (+5 seconds).. If I use the IP address of the EC2 instead of NLB DNS the response is very good (less than 100ms).

Can somebody point me what is the issue? Any configuration screw up I did while creating NLB?

I have been researching for the past 2 days and couldn't find any solution.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Hard to speculate without more info.  You're using an [endpoint integration](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-endpoint-integrations-with-private-vpcs/)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue that was due to failing health checks.  When all health checks fails, the targets are tried randomly (typically target in each AZ), however, at that stage I had only configured an EC2 in one of the AZs.  The solution was to fix the health checks.  They require the SecurityGroup (on the EC2 instances) to allow the entire VPC CIDR range (or at least the port the health checks are using).